# Add Drawer layout into main activity

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have created one application.It works great but now i want to include navigation drawer in the main activity.I know the code templates but for that i need to create new activity.My question is how to include  the drawer layout into existing activity which contains only Recycler view and the fab button,if it is possible to include?sorry for the big question.

Comment: you can extend your navigation activity to activity you want to use

Comment: i can't get you man sorry.am completely new to android

Comment: @Arun Basker, have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 9):

You can add NavigationDrawer step-by-step by following below procedures:

1) Set your activities parent layout as **DrawerLayout**:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
```

2) Add **NavigationView** at the bottom of DrawerLayout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

3) Add a xml file in menu folder under res folder called **activity_main_drawer.xml** for menu items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Home" />
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Directory" />
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="About Us" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

4) Implement **NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener** in your activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
}
```

5) Add **onNavigationItemSelected()** method to define your action on navigation item selected.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

6) Configure DrawerLayout and set listener to your NavigationView in onCreate() of activity:

```
  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
  drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
  toggle.syncState();

  NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

7) Add nav_header_main.xml to your layout folder;

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to add the toolbar, paste the following code at the top inside DrawerLayout  :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And close CoordinatorLayout right before the NavigationView:

```
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Let me know how it works.

Comment: what about nav_header..sorry i cant post my code for some security purpose

Comment: hey what about the toolbar ;)

Comment: I've added the Toolbar too. Please check.

Comment: hey done.but one thing when i click the cam navigation the intent is not working it automatically just close the drawer.

Comment: Have you added intent code to onNavigationItemSelected() ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put below code in activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: i can't extend dbactivity into  AppCompatActivity .