# Where do I put the nav_host portion of the xml code?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am trying to figure out where I should be putting the nav_host in my xml files. I am not fully understanding how to get around my application fragments in general.

I have read this [Add Drawer layout into main activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687639/add-drawer-layout-into-main-activity)

I had most of this working before trying to add the Navigation host (Meaning I could use the drawer menu and navigate). I have not been able to navigate from a fragment to anywhere else with a button that is on that fragment.

My current activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
    
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        
    
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/mainActivityHost"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>
    
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Is where I have the nav_host correct? Or should I have a different Fragment all together for the nav_host?

My MainActivity.class

```
    package com.signin.app;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
    import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
    import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
    
    import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
    
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    
        private Toolbar toolbar;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();
    
            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    
            // The program should always start on home.
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainActivityHost, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
            }
        }
    
        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();
    
            if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
    
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_signin) {
    
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_flights) {
    
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_hotels) {
    
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
    
            }
    
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    //
    //    @Override
    //    public void onBackPressed() {
    //        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    //            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    //        } else {
    //            super.onBackPressed();
    //        }
    //    }
    
    }
```

Before I messed with it I could open the drawer click the menu items and go to a fragment, so pretending that still worked the problem was that I could go to Signin fragment, but the buttons on that fragment would not take me anywhere, they mostly just crashed the application.

````
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;


public class SigninFragment extends Fragment {
    private EditText editText;
    private Button btn_signup, btn_signin, btn_forgot_pass;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container,false);

        editText = view.findViewById(R.id.email);
        btn_signup = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btn_signin = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_signin);
        btn_forgot_pass = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_forgot_pass);

        btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sign Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.nav_signup);
            }
        });

        btn_signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sign in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}```
Also, please note that nav_signup is not in the drawer menu so I wasn't sure where I was supposed to identify it, (i.e., in the fragment_signup.xml, in its own menu, somewhere else.) right now the id for fragment_signup, is `android:id="@+id/nav_signup"`
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question
`Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.nav_signup);` - it should do the navigation and `R.id.nav_signup` should be destination or action. I'm not sure what `R.id.nav_signup` is atm. If destination then probably it should be fragment id.

- Here's doc about navigations https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#java
- And here is Google course about navigation between fragments https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-fragments-navigation-component#6 (This guide is in Kotlin but that's just a syntax difference, hopefully still can be useful)

  - And the final code of this is here https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-words-app (it uses navigation/nav_graph.xml to define navigations between fragments)
  - And for example in *src/main/java/com/example/wordsapp/LetterAdapter.kt* has navigation to different fragment.

```kotlin
       holder.button.setOnClickListener {
            // LetterListFragmentDirections is defined in nav_graph.xml
            val action = LetterListFragmentDirections.actionLetterListFragmentToWordListFragment(letter = holder.button.text.toString())
            // Navigate using that action
            holder.view.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
```

I haven't used fragments a long time, but I hope this will be helpful :)

Comment: Thank you for these resources, I will look them over. However, I do not think the Kotlin information is relevant as I am coding in Java.